# C - function to return curved result

Tags: c, math, equation-solving

I have a general programming challenge for you all. I've been scratching my head trying to figure out the best way to do this...

I'm working in C and I've got a "speed" value that is passed to my program. It ranges from 0-255. This speed value needs to correspond to a millisecond time delay built into the program.

```
    unsigned char currentSpeed; //this is passed into my function, range 0-255
    unsigned long SlowestSpeedMillis = 3000; //in milliseconds
    if (currentSpeed > 0)
    {
       unsigned long Interval = ((256 - currentSpeed)*SlowestSpeedMillis)/255;

    }else{ //currentSpeed = 0
       //When Interval is zero, the program will freeze
       Interval = 0;
    }
```

Here's some sample results:
currentSpeed of **1** results in **3000** milliseconds (slowest)
currentSpeed of **128** results in **~1500** milliseconds (exactly half)
currentSpeed of **255** results in **~11** milliseconds (fastest)

The problem is that I would like it to be a curved result where it stays in the lower numbers and then quickly goes to 3000 at the end... I want the user to have the choice to make the program go as slow as 3000, but most values leading up to it aren't as important. Such as this:
currentSpeed of **1** results in **3000** milliseconds (slowest)
currentSpeed of **128** results in **~750** milliseconds **(1/4th of potential)**
currentSpeed of **255** results in **~11** milliseconds (fastest, anything close to zero)

Any ideas how to do this programmatically? Perhaps with some kind of equation?

Comment: There are many equations that start slow and grow quickly, such as Exponential, Quadratic, Tangent.... Since you don't seem picky on the details, pick one and use it until it *isn't* appropriate anymore.

Comment: Why not just use a lookup table of 256 precalculated values? Then you can use whatever function you like to generate them. Storing `currentSpeed` as an unsigned char would make your function more stable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally in math you might do something like:

```
(currentSpeed / 255) * 3000
```

for linear, and to get a bit of a curve use a power:

```
((currentSpeed / 255) * (currentSpeed / 255)) * 3000
```

But, in integer math that doesn't work because (currentSpeed / 255) will almost always be zero.

To do this without floating point you have to scale up first before division.

```
((3000 * currentSpeed) * currentSpeed) / (255 * 255)
```

Comment: This is almost perfect... except I need the inverse of it so that when currentspeed is 255, the result is almost 0. What do you think? 
`currentSpeed of 1 results in 3000 milliseconds (slowest) 
currentSpeed of 128 results in ~750 milliseconds (1/4th of potential) 
currentSpeed of 255 results in ~11 milliseconds (fastest, anything close to zero)`

Comment: Just invert it then ... "int x = 255 - currentSpeed", then use "x" in the equation instead of currentSpeed. You can scale currentSpeed a litte like "x = RANGE*(255-currentSpeed)+N" to make it invert range from N to RANGE+N. You can also adjust "3000" a bit, like "((3000-11)*x)*x/(255*255)+11" - this gives your desired result of 11 to 3000 milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
unsigned char currentSpeed; // range 0-255
unsigned long SlowestSpeedMillis = 3000; // in milliseconds
unsigned long Interval;
if (currentSpeed > 0)
{
   Interval = SlowestSpeedMillis/currentSpeed;

} else {
   Interval = 0;
}
```

1 is mapped to 3000, and 255 is mapped to 11.